# How to limit jquery click on ui-header to header only and not tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Good day all,

**Problem**

I've got an issue that is potentially very simple to solve. I'm trying to create an event handler in my code that is run **only** when the ui header is clicked on the tabs interface. I can get this to run fine, however, I'm unable to limit the click to the header only and clicking on the tabs also invokes the click event (even tho I've explicitly set a :not() filter on the li elements.)

**Html Code**

```
<div id="iframescroll">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id='page1'>Hey, this is page 1</div>
    <div id='page2'>Howdie -welocme to page 2</div>
</div>
```

**Extra css**

```
#iframescroll{
    max-width: 415px;
}

ul.ui-widget-header{
    cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(function () {
    // set up tabs
    var $tabs = $("#iframescroll").tabs();

    // method to expand/contract tabs window
    var isWide = false;
    $('.ui-widget-header:not(.ui-state-default)').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!isWide) {
            $('#iframescroll').css('max-width', 415);
            $(this).css('cursor', 'zoom-out');
        } else {
            $('#iframescroll').css('max-width', 1200);
            $(this).css('cursor', 'zoom-in');
        }
        isWide = !isWide;
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've setup a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue, as it's not so easy to visualise what I'm attempting purely thro the code: [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimibt/m22pB/)

Looking fwd to responses.

**[edit]** - i'm not wedded to the structure above, so if it requires structural change to make it work, party on it hard.

Comment: add e.stopPropagation();

Comment: alas, that doesn't solve the issue - tho is a nice and relevant suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

The function will stop the click event from bubbling up to the parent element and triggering your header click function. Here's the fiddle with the changes. Just add the function below to your code
http://jsfiddle.net/jbeeio/RA2q8/

```
$('.ui-widget-header li').on('click',function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Adding this function will also make your ':not(.ui-state-default)' unnecessary.

Comment: nice one, this is the kind of alternate view i was looking for. this works fine

Comment: also, you got yourself your first SO accepted answer -welcome to sO and thanks for the assist!! may the successive answers be as fruitful ;)

Comment: Thanks :)  I've been referring to SO since I first started programming, and finally decided to chime in.

Comment: may your future chimes ring as loudly :) - have a grt weekend

Comment: one point i would add tho, is why the :not() filter in this case doesn't work as I had hoped for??

Comment: I feel like the :not() selector only works on sibling elements.

Comment: Ahhhhh! Don't commit that. It's totally just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Use e.stopPropagation() event

```
$(function () {
// set up tabs
var $tabs = $("#iframescroll").tabs();

// method to expand/contract tabs window
var isWide = false;
$('.ui-widget-header:not(.ui-state-default)').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!isWide) {
        $('#iframescroll').css('max-width', 415);
        $(this).css('cursor', 'zoom-out');
    } else {
        $('#iframescroll').css('max-width', 1200);
        $(this).css('cursor', 'zoom-in');
    }
    isWide = !isWide;
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: sorry, i tried this in both the core code at issue, as well as the simplified jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jimibt/m22pB/2/) to no avail. can you update with a link to the jsfiddle that you got this working with if possible. thanks... appreciated

Comment: user3310208 answered well :D

Comment: yes, he/she certainly did, tho you were instrumental in focussing the problem so you bag a +1 as well :)